# Can we change the hook firing sequence?

Tags: hooks, admin, actions

In admin, I need to fire the `save_post` action before firing the `transition_post_status` hook. But according to [this](http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/), the `transition_post_status` fires first before the post is saved.

How can I reverse it? I tried changing the priority order below, but I don't think it works cos it's for different functions firing for the same action.

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'save_post', $plugin_admin_listings, 'save_meta_data', 9, 2 );
$this->loader->add_action( 'transition_post_status', $plugin_admin_listings, 'transition_post_status', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: No, I don't think so. What are you trying to do? Can't you run the save meta action on transition post status hook too?

Comment: what is the problem that you're hoping to solve by doing this? This is not something that can be done

Comment: Ok. On this plugin that I'm modding, an email is sent to the user when the transition_post_status action is fired (draft -> published). But I want to fire it only after the save_post action since I want some data to be firstly saved and then email that data to the user. I can't do the emailing in the save_post since each time the post is saved, the email is fired. I only wish to fire when the post is published.

Comment: If you only want to run the code when the post is published but not when it's updated then that is something that can be solved and has been asked about on this site before. Changing the order of the hooks though is not possible, and if it were it would cause new problems unrelated to your task

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, but the problem is I need the post to be saved first cos in I'm updating its post meta. Then, when it gets published, my site should trigger the transition_post_status to send the email to the user tell them about the post meta value. Or do you think I can use js to do this, like get transition_post_status to read the value from the input text field?

Comment: none of those, focus back on fixing your original problem, not fixing the technical solution you attempted, if you can't send the email until the post has been saved then don't attempt to do that until the post has been saved, aka don't do it on transition_post_status. You ran into a problem that if you notify on save_post you get new emails when a post is updated. Rather than ask how to fix that, you devised a solution which lead you to this new problem and are here asking how to fix the problem with the solution to your problem, aka the X Y problem, a common fallacy

Comment: As I said, your original problem has well known solutions, this new problem you're asking about however does not, and the solution you've devised is a hard dead end. ( the solution for the problem with the solution to your problem ). Do the update on `save_post` then ask how to make it only happen when a post is first published, or how to only send it once.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could

- create a new member in your $plugin_admin_listings class that's an array of post IDs published in this page cycle
- in your transition_post_status add the IDs to that array
- in save_meta_data as you save each post check if its ID is in the published_posts array and then send the email then

You probably need an array not a single ID in case this can be triggered from an admin bulk action (I'd guess so?). However this falls apart though if the two hooks run in separate page loads (I'd guess they don't though). If that was the case you could e.g. add two post_meta timestamps

- last published timestamp (set in transition post status)
- last published email sent timestamp (set when you send the email)

In your save_post hook you could check if the first is after the second, and then send a new email. (And it's also possible one of the existing dates on the WP_Post object would work too, but I forget precisely when they're set.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I "solved" it by placing my intended code (`update_post_meta`) inside the function that is hooked by `transition_post_status`.